# Using websockets with java?

Tags: java, websocket

I was wondering if anyone is aware of tutorial/resource to learn how to connect to a websocket server using a JAVA application, instead of html5. I've been searching and can't find anything as they all give a server websocket example in java but client side in html5.

I know you can do http GET/POST in java, so I was wondering what step I would need to enable websockets via java based console app, vs html5.

```
try{
connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();
conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
connection.connect();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStreamReader()));
sb = new StringBuilder();

while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
sb.append("Recieved: "+line+"\n");
}

}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
connection.disconnect();
reader = null;
sb=null;
connection=null;

}
```

how can I turn this method here into a websocket connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Java EE 7 WebSocket API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/). It has a `javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer` class which has a `connectToServer()` method that accepts a `ClientEndpoint`. I haven't used a Java client myself so I don't have any sample code, but if you search for examples with those classes and method you might find something.

[edit] some links:

- [Java API for WebSocket: JSR 356](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356)
- [Glassfish application Server (Java EE 7 Reference implementation)](https://glassfish.java.net)
- [Tyrus - JSR 356 Reference Implementation](https://tyrus.java.net), [user guide](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.4/user-guide.html)

To be fair - there is plenty of other implementations, you can take a look at [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) or [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).